# How to install pycairo with python3.2+?

Tags: python-3.x, pycairo

I have a problem with installing the pycairo in my project. Please see the below error,

```
Downloading/unpacking git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Cloning http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo to /tmp/pip-puo8hs-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Failed
    /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Failed

/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
```

Please solve my problem ?

Comment: What Operating system?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS